# How to record multiple screens and audio at once on MacBook using ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

## Task

I want to be able to record three screens at one time, and record the microphone. Then combine the three recordings and the microphone  recording into one output file.

## Detection of inputs

The listing of both video and audio inputs can be found by using `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""`. This is can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689029/capture-microphone-input-with-ffmpeg-on-mac-and-streaming).

## One Screen Recording

I can record **one** of my three screens at a time by using `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "3" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 output.mov`, where the `"3"` can be replaced with `"1"` or `"2"` to individually record one screen for 5 seconds. This is found at [recording one screen for a duration of time.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733635/how-to-capture-a-timed-screen-recording-on-a-mac-with-ffmpeg#39737275)

## Post Process videos into one screen recording

The most recent version of `ffmpeg` provides for combining multiple `.mov` files into one "stack". [Stacking screen recordings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552565/vertically-or-horizontally-stack-mosaic-several-videos-using-ffmpeg/33764934#33764934) discusses how to post process videos into one output file.

## Record audio

The audio of the built in microphone or usb microphone can be recorded using `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":1" audiocapture.mp3`. A description of this command can be found at [recording audio with ffmpeg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326388/terminal-command-to-record-audio-through-macbook-microphone?noredirect=1).

## What I want

The following recorded until I hit `q`, with a good quality audio.

```
---------------------------------
|               |               |
|  1920 X 1080  |  1920 X 1080  |
|               |               |
---------------------------------
    -----------------
    |               |
    |  2560 X 1600  |   
    |               |
    -----------------
```

## Current Progress

This command: 
`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "3" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -f avfoundation -i "2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -f avfoundation -i "1" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]xstack=inputs=3:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0[v]" -map "[v]" output.mov` results in 
[image: The three screens with thread message queue blocking warning]

I am getting the message `Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)`, and do not know how to handle this. I also am not recording audio here.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. You seem to know what you want to do and how to do it....

Comment: I put a "what I want" section. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: Not really... what have you tried and which bit is causing errors or not working?

Comment: I updated my current progress. Does does that help? I am now stuck.

Comment: Increase your encoding speed by adding `-preset veryfast` and add `-thread_queue_size 512 -rtbufsize 2G` before each `-i`.